# Flutter: Table_calendar custom header change text

Tags: flutter, dart

in my flutter app i build stateless widget with table_calendar package.

in this widget i have a custom header if i click on the arrow_left icon it switch the page to left also the same with right.

but the text in the middle, for example this one in the picture "August" don't change.
how can i solve it?

This is how it looks like:
[image]

```
Calendar(
  pageController: PageController(),
),
```

the calendar widget:

```
class Calendar extends StatelessWidget {
  Calendar({
    Key? key,
    required this.pageController,
  }) : super(key: key);

  PageController pageController;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    DateTime focusedDay = DateTime.now();
    String headerText = DateFormat.MMMM().format(focusedDay);

    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 26),
      child: Card(
        color: Colors.white,
        child: Column(
          children: [
            Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
              children: [
                IconButton(
                  onPressed: () {
                    pageController.previousPage(
                      duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 300),
                      curve: Curves.easeOut,
                    );
                    focusedDay = focusedDay.subtract(const Duration(days: 30));
                  },
                  icon: const Icon(
                    Icons.keyboard_arrow_left,
                    color: Colors.black,
                  ),
                ),
                Text(headerText),
                IconButton(
                  onPressed: () {
                    pageController.nextPage(
                      duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 300),
                      curve: Curves.easeOut,
                    );
                    focusedDay = focusedDay.add(const Duration(days: 30));
                  },
                  icon: const Icon(
                    Icons.keyboard_arrow_right,
                    color: Colors.black,
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
            TableCalendar(
              firstDay: DateTime.utc(2010, 10, 16),
              lastDay: DateTime.utc(2030, 3, 14),
              focusedDay: focusedDay,
              onCalendarCreated: (controller) => pageController = controller,
              headerVisible: false,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can edit your header style. Using headerStyle .

Example:-

```
headerStyle: HeaderStyle(
          leftChevronVisible: false,
          rightChevronVisible: false,
          headerPadding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20.0, vertical: 10.0),
          titleTextStyle: currentTheme.value == "light"
              ? ThemeText.calenderHeaderTextStyle
              : ThemeText.calenderHeaderTextStyle2,
          formatButtonVisible: false,
        ),
```

I think this is useful for you.

Answer (score 0):

call SetState inside of onPressed

Here is the example:

```
IconButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  print(_focusedDay);
                  pageController.previousPage(
                    duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 300),
                    curve: Curves.easeOut,
                  );
                  _focusedDay = _focusedDay.subtract(const Duration(days: 30));
                    setState((){});
                },
                icon: const Icon(
                  Icons.keyboard_arrow_left,
                  color: Colors.black,
                ),
              ),
```